# Unable to select (click) Sub-menu item

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, stylesheet

I have the following website:

http://miraj.quranprojectreading.org/

The issue that I'm faced with is that the sub-menu item is not selectable. For example, if you hover over 'About Us', you are unable to click on the sub-menu items.

Any idea how I can fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is a hidden Gap in your main menu and sub menu. By inspecting your css with firebug, you have something like this in your css :

```
#access ul ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(143, 235, 251, 0.9);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 160px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Now `top:24px;` is too far from main menu. Change it to -

```
#access ul ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(143, 235, 251, 0.9);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 160px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

And now you can select you sub menu.